# Bash - executing commands in sequence but ignore if one fails

Tags: node.js, bash

I have the following bash command:

```
echo "istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/empty.js --dir ./coverage/empty.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test6.js --dir ./coverage/test6.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test7-start.js --dir ./coverage/test7-start.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test8.js --dir ./coverage/test8.js
istanbul cover /Users/amills001c/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/test/build-tests/test9.js --dir ./coverage/test9.js
istanbul report" | bash
```

I want to execute each line sequentially. But if one command fails (exits with a non-zero exit code?), I want to continue anyway.

Is the above sufficient? I believe using && will not continue if a process fails. I am using newline characters to delimit commands, if that is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is sufficient. You can try it and see:

```
$ echo "true
true
false
true
echo 'Still running'" | bash
Still running
```